# Embedding a flash file (swf) in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

How can we include (nicely) a `swf` file in a Rails application?

By the way, I tried the `swf_fu` plugin but it didn't work. When I call my swf file located in the `swfs` directory, it tells me that the method is not found:

```
undefined method swf_tag
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not about embedded programming.  Retagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.tools FlashEmbed](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/toolbox/flashembed.html) is the most popular way to cross-browse integration swf file into a page. you can do it this way:

```
flashembed("flash", "my_object.swf");
```

UPDATE for Rails 2.3.x, you can use custom helper to eliminate file caching on proxy/ISP side:

view:

```
<%= custom_assets('/swfs/my_object', '.swf') -%>
```

helper:

```
def custom_assets(source, ext)
  path = File.join(Rails.root, 'public', source) + ext
  asset_id = File.exist?(path) ? File.mtime(path).to_i.to_s : ''
  "#{source}?#{asset_id}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a rails method that can do it (server side method)?

Comment: flash swf is a client application. if you have no interaction your flash application with server side (video streaming, photo capture), no need to do extra work on it

Comment: I'm ok ... I just wanted a pure rails method. Anyway, yours is working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: where shall I add the file my_object.swf at the assets folder ??